# временная ссылка видео

Tags: php, javascript

Как можно сгенерировать js или php временную ссылку которая будет действовать ДО полной буферизации видео после чего ссылка на видео станет не доступным... 
Например

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="/videos/fh879y8.dat" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```

На ум приходит только использование БД но как МНЕ кажется эта не рациональное использование БД и после буферизации сбрасывать урл. Есть какие варианты без БД наведите на мысль в какую сторону копать....

Comment: Я не совсем понял если чесно поэтому пишу в коментариях.Вообщем я могу предложить скажем через пока сесия не закончиться выводить видео(это в php).а в JS можна поставить время и по окончанию этого временни задавать через CSS display:none.Не знаю помогло ли хоть немного мои идеи, но надеюсь...

Answer (score 1):

я на php смог придумать вот что

```
    <?php
//newEmptyPHP.php
    $hash = $_GET['hash'];
    $filename = $_GET['filename'];

    $ip = md5(getenv("REMOTE_ADDR")."key".date("i"));
    //var_dump($ip);
    if ($hash == $ip and $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] != '') {
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $url = explode("?", $url);
        $url = $url[1];
        if (isset($url)) {
            $filename .="?" . $url;
        }
        header("Content-Type: video/x-mp4");
        header("X-Accel-Redirect:/rvp/" . $filename);
        readfile("/rvp/".$filename);
        die();
    }
    echo "403";
    ?>
    <?php
    //index.php
    $ip = md5(getenv("REMOTE_ADDR")."key".date("i"));
    ?>

    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="/newEmptyPHP.php?hash=<?php echo $ip;?>&filename=video1.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    </video>
```

В свою очередь запрос происходит по пути "/newEmptyPHP.php?hash=2d093474d45b8e7eba4a342c474c696d&filename=video1.mp4" которая и идёт уже в тег видео. и даже если и есть ссылка скачать не получится так как SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]. Насколько правильно не знаю но вроде работает. В свою как можно понять будет действовать пока минута запроса будет равна текущей минуте